# Is it permissible to recite Surahs while walking?

Tags: quran-recitation

My educational institution is at a distance of about 1.5 KM from Bus stop. I usually cover this distance while reciting Surahs.
What I want to ask is, Is it permissible to recite Surahs from Qur'an while walking, or Is it against the grace of Holy Book?.

It also helps me to memorize Surahs easily.
I intend to do so in a voice only audible to me of course.

Comment: yes off course, In fact it is a beautiful deed to do so.

Comment: Well obviously. Dont we have duas to say when we are travelling/ on a journey or while walking to a masjid it is advisable to recite "darood-sharif".

Comment: It may be worth clarifying if you're only reciting from memory, or reading from the Mus'haf.

Comment: What made you think that it wouldn't be permissible?

Comment: @AhmedHan I have mentioned that in question

Comment: I have an MP3 player for listening Quran and audio books while I am outside. It becomes very beneficial. I don't waste my time in travel this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is permissible to recite the Qur'an in all conditions - walking, riding, or lying down.

`Abdullah ibn Mughaffal (may Allah be pleased with him) said:

> I saw the Prophet (peace be upon him) reciting (Qur’an) while he was
>   riding his she-camel or camel. He was reciting the Surah of Al-Fat-h
>   or part of the Surah of Al- Fat-h very softly and in an attractive
>   vibrating tone. (Related by Al-Bukhari)

It is reported in Al-Bukhari and Muslim that `Aishah (may Allah be pleased with her) said:

> The Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) would recline in my lap  when I was menstruating and recite the Qur'an.

It is reported that `Aishah (may Allah be pleased with her) used to recite her daily portion of Qur'an while she was reclining in bed.

Abu Musa Al-Ash`ary (may Allah be pleased with him) said:

> "I recite the Qur'an in my Salah and in my bed."

Source: [Etiquette of reciting the Qur'an](http://alifta.com/Fatawa/fatawaChapters.aspx?View=Page&PageID=37&PageNo=1&BookID=15)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, surely you can. And also I recommend you to have look at natural perspectives around yourself and think about them. Look at Trees, Water, Soils, Folwers, Mountains, Sky, Clouds, Sunshine, etc. In my idea following confirms this situation well [[3:191]](http://tanzil.net/#3:191):

> الَّذِينَ يَذْكُرُونَ اللَّـهَ قِيَامًا وَقُعُودًا وَعَلَىٰ
>   جُنُوبِهِمْ وَيَتَفَكَّرُونَ فِي خَلْقِ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضِ
>   رَبَّنَا مَا خَلَقْتَ هَـٰذَا بَاطِلًا سُبْحَانَكَ فَقِنَا عَذَابَ
>   النَّارِ
>
> Who remember Allah while standing or sitting or [lying] on their sides
>   and give thought to the creation of the heavens and the earth,
>   [saying], "Our Lord, You did not create this aimlessly; exalted are
>   You [above such a thing]; then protect us from the punishment of the
>   Fire.